# Debug this code. What is the problem with y1?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a problem with my y1 variable:
No matter the value that I input in the browser it defaults to 1 in the script. I don't understand what the base problem could be. Maybe I have a default value somewhere in my code and I don't know or I can't see

```js
let x0 = null;
let y0 = null;
let x1 = null;
let y1 = null;
let xp = null;
let yp = null;
function Interp(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp) {
    yp = y0 + ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0)) * (xp - x0);
    return yp;
}
function Xtrap(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp){
    yp = y0 + ((xp-x0)/(x1-x0)) * (y1-y0)
  return yp;
}

function Evaluate(){
    x0 = document.getElementById('x0').value;
    y0 = document.getElementById('y0').value;
    x1 = document.getElementById('x1').value;
    y1 = document.getElementById('y1').value;
    xp = document.getElementById('xp').value;
    console.log(x0,x1,y0,1,xp)
    if (xp > x0 && xp < x1) {
        console.log(Interp(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp))
    } else if (xp > x0 && xp > x1) {
        console.log(Xtrap(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp))
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

.container{
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 80px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #b6a9a9, -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }

    .call-box{
        width: 200px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    .point{
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 600px;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
        background: transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #babecc; inset: -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }
#button{
    margin: 15px 0 0 5px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 42;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #b6acac, -5px -5px 10px #faf4f4;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-70%);
}
#button:active{
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #babeec, inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewpoint' content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Interp-Xtrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div div class="container">
        <div class="call-box">
            <form name="Inerp-Xtrap">
                <label for="x0">Point 1: X0:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="x0" name="x0" size="10px">
                <label for="y0">Poiny 1: Y0:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="y0" name="y0" size="10px">
                <label for="x1">Point 2: X1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="x1" name="x1" size="10px">
                <label for="y1">Point 2: Y1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="y1" name="y1" size="10px">
                <label for="xp">Point 3: Xp:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="xp" name="xp" size="10px">
                <button type="button" id="button" onclick="Evaluate()">Evaluate</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <h1>Interp-Xtrap</h1>
</body>

<script src="my.js"></script>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you find out what the problem is.
I have renamed the variable, changed the id in the form but it still defaults to 1 all the same.

Comment: `console.log(x0,x1,y0,1,xp)` Why is there a `1` here?

Comment: Give some example input and output. I have no idea what your code *should* be doing

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(x0,x1,y0,1,xp)` here mentioned 1 at place of `y1`

```js
let x0 = null;
let y0 = null;
let x1 = null;
let y1 = null;
let xp = null;
let yp = null;
function Interp(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp) {
    yp = y0 + ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0)) * (xp - x0);
    return yp;
}
function Xtrap(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp){
    yp = y0 + ((xp-x0)/(x1-x0)) * (y1-y0)
  return yp;
}

function Evaluate(){
    x0 = document.getElementById('x0').value;
    y0 = document.getElementById('y0').value;
    x1 = document.getElementById('x1').value;
    y1 = document.getElementById('y1').value;
    xp = document.getElementById('xp').value;
    console.log(x0,x1,y0,y1,xp)
    if (xp > x0 && xp < x1) {
        console.log(Interp(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp))
    } else if (xp > x0 && xp > x1) {
        console.log(Xtrap(x0, y0, x1, y1, xp))
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

.container{
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 80px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #b6a9a9, -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }

    .call-box{
        width: 200px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    .point{
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 600px;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
        background: transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #babecc; inset: -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }
#button{
    margin: 15px 0 0 5px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 42;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #b6acac, -5px -5px 10px #faf4f4;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-70%);
}
#button:active{
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #babeec, inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewpoint' content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Interp-Xtrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div div class="container">
        <div class="call-box">
            <form name="Inerp-Xtrap">
                <label for="x0">Point 1: X0:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="x0" name="x0" size="10px">
                <label for="y0">Poiny 1: Y0:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="y0" name="y0" size="10px">
                <label for="x1">Point 2: X1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="x1" name="x1" size="10px">
                <label for="y1">Point 2: Y1:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="y1" name="y1" size="10px">
                <label for="xp">Point 3: Xp:</label>
                <input type="text" class="point" id="xp" name="xp" size="10px">
                <button type="button" id="button" onclick="Evaluate()">Evaluate</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <h1>Interp-Xtrap</h1>
</body>

<script src="my.js"></script>
</html>
```